# aws autoscale mod_jk

Tags: tomcat, jboss, amazon-web-services, mod-jk

We have an Apache with mod_jk that act as a load balancer for Jboss 5.1 app server.

mod_jk doesn't support the dynamic configuration of httpd workers. Is there a way to handle dynamic scale up/down of the JBoss instances using AWS autoscale without restarting apache?

Thanks